# Count Line Numbers of File in Java

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I am trying to count line no. of a file **using Java LineNumberReader**. The output comes with problem. The problem is the **alternative lines are displayed** like line no. 1,3,5,... and on counting total no of lines  **i got half no. of the total actual lines. Here is the code**

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class countLine{
    File file=null;
    public countLine(){
            file =new File("E:\\test.txt");
        getFileData();
    }
    public void getFileData(){
            try{ 
                if(file.exists()){
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr); 
                    int linenumber = 0;
                        do{
                System.out.println(lnr.readLine());
                        linenumber++;
                        }while (lnr.readLine() != null);
                        System.out.println("Total number of lines : " + linenumber);
                        lnr.close();
                }else{
                     System.out.println("File does not exists!");
                }
            }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
    public static void main(String h[]){
        countLine cl = new countLine(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: each call to `readLine` reads a line...

Comment: line 1,3,5 and so on are printed. on counting total no. of lines for ex. there are 10 lines then in output i get only 5

Comment: And use lnr.getLineNumber() for the line number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every lnr.readLine() read a line from the file and return it.
You are making two reads:
1)At the System.out.println
2)At the while statement

You need make a call to readLine method,
save the result at variable and when it a null is the end of the file.

Take a look at:

```
int linenumber = 0;
String tmp = new String();
while ((tmp = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
    linenumber++;
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Why are you initializing `tmp` When it's assigned in the very next line? And what does 'if the file empty it's not count!!!' mean? And how many times are you going to answer this question?

Comment: I'm rewrite my previous answer, it really don't be so understood sorry for that.. :)

Answer (score 7):

You read the line twice, once with  `System.out.println(lnr.readLine());` and once with `while (lnr.readLine() != null);`

Combining the two other answers into one gives correct line count as well as the ability of doing the `System.out.println(...)` with line content:

```
int linenumber = 0;
String tmp = new String();
while ((tmp = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
    linenumber++;
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: what is the proper way ?

Comment: As one of the other answers suggested, depending on the fact whether you need the System.out.println of line content (Naor's answer) or not (laune's answer).

Comment: Yeah, that's ok. In my understanding your original code had one more bug, the do-while counted one line too much, if I see it correctly. But I did not unit-tested that assumption.

Comment: I am sorry I was too fast embracing the two answers. Naor's answer counts one line too much, you would need to initialize the linenumber with -1.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been enough for counting:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr); 
while (lnr.readLine() != null);
System.out.println( lnr.getLineNumber() );
lnr.close();
```

**Added later** Or, if you need to print lines (+ line numbers):

```
String line = null;
while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println( lnr.getLineNumber() + " " +  lnr.getLineNumber() );
}
```

Comment: thanks..but what to do if i want to print content of that line number

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of lines with two lines of code: something like

```
lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
int count = LineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
```

E&OE